# converting an address from a char type to a ip6addr in Contiki-NG

Tags: string, contiki, contiki-ng

I'm sending an IPV6 address in a packet data section, that is beside the sender and receiver addresses.

I did convert it to a char using uiplib_ipaddr_snprint() and added it to the package and sent it.
Everything is working perfectly, I managed to cut the address from the data, however, I'm having trouble converting it using uiplib_ip6addrconv() but when I try to print the address is empty!

I'm not sure where the error is, but in regards to string manipulations I think everything is working correctly, the address is printed in the string form correctly, however, the converting doesn't seem to be working and I'm not sure why, any help is appreciated it.
This is how I get the address from the data of the packet, and p contains the correct address, then try to convert it to an ip6addr where things doesn't work.
Thank you.

```
int size = 40;
char *p;
p = strstr(str,"fe");
printf("%s\n", p);
const uip_ip6addr_t *addr_2;
uiplib_ip6addrconv(p, addr_2);
```

Comment: Whats is the variable `str` in your example? Also, never use malloc/free in Contiki: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Memory-allocation !

Comment: str is the const uint8_t *data from the callback function, I did try without it and still, it didn't work, it didn't do anything actually for me, I will delete it.

Comment: Regarding `uiplib_ip6addrconv`, you are supposed to pass a "A pointer to a uip_ip4addr_t that will be filled in with the numerical representation of the address." - https://g-oikonomou-contiki-ng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/group__uip-addr-lib.html So, it seems your code just has an API usage mistake. Once you fix it, the question can be closed.

Comment: The documentation has an error - it shoud be "a pointer to uip_ip6addr_t" obviously. But this is not your issue anyway.

Comment: I took the usage form the code in github, this is how the function is defined: int uiplib_ip6addrconv(const char *addrstr, uip_ip6addr_t *addr); and I believe this is what I did but still it didn't work. https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/blob/48a3799e2d2c52e91cb7153b163bb26dfd9a4b4f/os/net/ipv6/uiplib.h#L74

Comment: The main issue is a way to convert a textual representation of an ipv6 address to a numerical form to use it with the uip library, this is the only function that Ive found that could do this in contiki-ng

Comment: The second parameter of the uiplib_ip6addrconv function should be a pointer to a variable where the result of the conversion is stored.

Comment: p is the string that contains the textual representation of the address, uip_ip6addr_t *addr_2; is the pointer to which to store the converted address

Comment: It's not possible to store IPv6 address in a pointer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question now. You might need to refresh your C knowledge about pointers and memory allocation. If the problem persists after you've fixed the calling code, edit and reopen it.